# Matcher won't match the Pattern in Android

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to develop an app that automatically reads a **One Time Password** from an incoming SMS. I have a class called `SMS` where I'm storing the currently read messages and a class called `SMSRule` that contains information about the possible OTP Senders.

The `SMSRule` also contains a `Pattern` variable that should be matched with the message to see if it really is the correct sender of the OTP.

Everything is going smooth except for the OTP extraction from the message. My SMS is containing the message, but when I try to match the `Pattern` against the message, my `match.find()` returns false.

Following are my files:

**OTPAutoRead.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import auro.widget.OTP.SMS.SMS;
import auro.widget.OTP.SMS.SMSRule;

/**
 * Created on 26/8/16.
 * @author Auro
 * @since 1.0
 */

public class OTPAutoRead extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = OTPAutoRead.class.getCanonicalName();

    private static final String mReadPermission = "android.permission.READ_SMS";
    private static final String mReceivePermission = "android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS";

    private List<SMSRule> smsRules;
    private Context context;
    private String OTP;

    public OTPAutoRead() {throw new InstantiationError("Empty Constructor");}

    public OTPAutoRead(@NonNull Context context, final List<SMSRule> smsRules) {

        if (smsRules == null || smsRules.size() == 0) {

            throw new AuroMissingRulesException("No SMS Rules Found");
        }

        this.smsRules = smsRules;
        this.context = context;
        CheckSMSReadPermission();

        IntentFilter itf = new IntentFilter();
        itf.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        itf.setPriority(999);
        context.registerReceiver(this,itf);

    }


    private void CheckSMSReadPermission() {

        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();

        int readPermission = packageManager.checkPermission(mReadPermission,packageName);
        int receivePermission = packageManager.checkPermission(mReceivePermission, packageName);

        boolean canRead = (readPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        if (!canRead)
            Toast.makeText(context,"Please enable SMS read permission for auto OTP read", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
                tryReceiveMessage(intent);
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Failed to read SMS", e);
        }
    }


    private void tryReceiveMessage(Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        SmsMessage[] messages = null;

        if (bundle != null) {

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            if (pdus != null) {
                messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    String messageFrom = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress().toUpperCase();
                    String messageBody = messages[i].getMessageBody().toUpperCase();

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Message is from: " + messageFrom + " and its content is: " + messageBody);

                    SMS sms = new SMS();
                    sms.setMessage(messageBody).setAddress(messageFrom);

                    processOTP(sms);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void processOTP(SMS sms) {

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < smsRules.size(); i ++) {

            if (sms.getAddress().toUpperCase().contains(smsRules.get(i).getSender().toUpperCase())) {

                Pattern pattern = smsRules.get(i).getOTPPattern();

                System.out.println(pattern.pattern());
                System.out.println(sms.getMessage());

                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sms.getMessage().toUpperCase());

                if (matcher.find()) {

                    OTP = matcher.group(1);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"Extracted OTP is: " + OTP);
                    Toast.makeText(context,"OTP RECEIVED IS: " + OTP,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Failed to extract OTP");
            }
        }
    }

    public String getOTP() {
        return OTP;
    }

}
```

**SMS.java**

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

/**
 * Created on 26/8/16.
 * @author Auro
 * @since 1.0
 */
public class SMS {

    private String mID;
    private String mAddress;
    private String mMessage;
    private boolean isRead = false;
    private String mTime;

    public String getID() {

        return mID;
    }

    public SMS setID(@NonNull final String ID) {

        mID = ID;
        return this;
    }

    public String getAddress() {

        return mAddress;
    }

    public SMS setAddress(@NonNull final String Address) {

        mAddress = Address;
        return this;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

    public SMS setMessage(@NonNull final String Message) {

        mMessage = Message;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isRead() {

        return isRead;
    }

    public SMS setReadState(boolean ReadState) {

        isRead = ReadState;
        return this;
    }

    public String getTime() {

        return mTime;
    }

    public SMS setTime(@NonNull String Time) {

        mTime = Time;
        return this;
    }
}
```

**SMSRule.java**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created on 26/8/16.
 * @author Auro
 * @since 1.0
 */
public class SMSRule {

    private String mSender;
    private String mGroupID;
    private Pattern mOTPPattern;


    private SMS sms;

    public String getSender() {

        return mSender;
    }

    public SMSRule setSender(final String sender) {

        mSender = sender;
        return this;
    }

    public String getGroupID() {

        return mGroupID;
    }

    public SMSRule setGroupID(final String groupID) {

        mGroupID = groupID;
        return this;

    }


    public Pattern getOTPPattern() {

        return mOTPPattern;
    }

    public SMSRule setOTPPattern(final Pattern otpPattern) {

        mOTPPattern = otpPattern;
        return this;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import auro.widget.OTP.OTPAutoRead;
import auro.juspay.widget.OTP.SMS.SMSRule;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        SMSRule rule = new SMSRule();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("One Time Password is (\\d{6})".toUpperCase());

        rule.setSender("BANK-XYZ");
        rule.setOTPPattern(pattern);

        List<SMSRule> smsRules = new ArrayList<>();
        smsRules.add(rule);

        OTPAutoRead otpAutoRead = new OTPAutoRead(this,smsRules);

        String OTP = otpAutoRead.getOTP();

        if (OTP != null)
        {
            editText.setText(OTP);
        }
    }

}
```

**Problem is**, when I run this in `Debug` mode, I get `matchFound = false`. I also tried changing the `regex` to

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("One Time Password is \d{6}".toUpperCase());`

It just wouldn't work

Following is a screenshot: -

[image]

Comment: For the record: you are posting an awful lot of code. Heard about that idea described in the help center about coming up with **minimal** examples? Wouldn't it be enough to just post A) expected input B) your patterns C) what happens? And you don't post screenshots.

Comment: Use toUpperCase on parts of the pattern that are literal. Don't use it on parts that are regex construct parts, like `\d{6}`, or \r, \n, \t. Also, in Java language, string's must be double escaped, so use something like `"..."..toUpperCase()) + "\\d{6}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert the pattern string to uppercase in `Pattern.compile("One Time Password is (\\d{6})".toUpperCase())`, `\d` (matching a digit) turns into `\D` (matching a non-digit).

Use `[0-9]` instead of the `\d` so that the pattern means the same, or just remove `toUpperCase()` and write the exact pattern, or use a pattern case insensitive flag.